# Silverlight 4.1.10111 security update broke my computer

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-update

Just seeing if anyone knows anything about this. I installed the 4.1.10111 SL security update today, and then went to run one of my SL 4 projects, and I get a failed to load pre-requites error message every time I debug (the error gets thrown by JavaScript in the host html page).

This is the MS KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2668562

I've tried un-installing the update, un-installing SL, and restoring from restore point before the update... VS still fails with the above stated error message, and I when I navigate to a SL site, I get a blank white page, or plug failure message.

Does anyone know a fix for this? **smacks head for trusting Microsoft's updates*

Comment: note: it didn't "break" my computer, I just can't develop or navigate to SL at all anymore.

Comment: Did you install Silverlight_Developer.exe?

Comment: Yes, the update installed both windows file listed in the link in the question. This is not good, as I have a deadline tomorrow... ugh.

Comment: Try to install the Silverlight 5 Developer Runtime? Then you can still develop Silverlight 4 applications

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting

Comment: Not sure what happened, but I had to just restore to an image prior to all this instead of a restore point. There's some issue with the the 5.0.6.1118.0 runtime conflicting with applications built in 4.1.10111.0 (or the version before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Silverlight_Developer.exe runtime that matches the version of Silverlight Runtime that you have installed.  Since you received the patch to 4.1.10111 of Silverlight Runtime, you must download that same version of the developer runtime and install it.

You can download the 4.1.10111 of the developer runtime here:  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28813

Also, someone nicely set up a site to identify what version of Silverlight Runtime you have at [silverlightruntime.com](http://silverlightversion.com). I have found this to be very useful.

EDIT:  I did just have to uninstall Silverlight 4.0 completely on my machine.  I was able to install JUST the developer version and it seems to be working well, unlike my experience with previous builds where I had to install one and then the other.

Comment: This did not work. I tried this numerous times. The WinUpdate that pushed down v4.1.1011 messed up something I could not fix with my computer. I restored to an image (not to a restore point), and all was well. This answer really describes how to develop in a specific runtime. I'll give you the +1, but the this did not fix the problem I faced with this update. I do keep multiple dev and client runtimes available for syncing version like you have here in the future.